# Protocol inheritance from class?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I read the documentation about [Protocols](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html) and can't find any information about protocol inheriting from a class, but the code compiles. As far as I remember protocols can only inherit other protocols, I have never seen protocol that inherits from a class. I don't even know a language that allows such behaviour.

```
class A {

}

protocol X: A {

}
// forced to inherit from class A, because of X protocol
class B: A, X {

}
```

Is it some kind of bug?

Comment: I think it's the same as `protocol X where Self:A` and that this short way to write it has been added recently (Swift 5?).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Implemented In Swift 5: From the [Swift 5 Release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2)

Protocols can now constrain their conforming types to those that subclass a given class. Two equivalent forms are supported:

```swift
protocol MyView: UIView { /*...*/ }
protocol MyView where Self: UIView { /*...*/ }
```

See this [tweet](https://twitter.com/johnsundell/status/1110491386636308480?lang=en) by John Sundell, showing a possible use case